# Php - csv export add absolute path to output

Tags: php, csv

Is it possible to add absolute path `http://domain` to the `filename.jpg`?
I don't want to edit the csv file and add it manually domain (http://).

**SQL database**

| id | caption | filename |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | caption1 | filename 1.jpg |
| 2 | caption2 | filename 2.jpg |
| 3 | caption3 | filename 3.jpg |
| 4 | caption4 | filename 4.jpg |

```
$sql = "SELECT caption, filename
FROM table"

$result = $database->query($sql);

function getRow($result) {
   return $result->fetch_assoc();
}

if (isset($_POST['download'])) {
    $file_name = 'csv_file.csv';
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=$file_name");
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Expires: 0');
    $csvoutput = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    $row = getRow($result);
    $headers = array_keys($row);
    fputcsv($csvoutput, $headers);
    fputcsv($csvoutput, $row);
    while ($row = getRow($result)) {
        fputcsv($csvoutput, $row);
    }
    fclose($csvoutput);
    exit;
}
```

**CSV output**

I wish I had such a result. Now is just what filename.jpg - filename2.jpg ...

| id | caption | filename |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | caption1 | http://domain/filename1.jpg |
| 2 | caption2 | http://domain/filename2.jpg |
| 3 | caption3 | http://domain/filename3.jpg |
| 4 | caption4 | http://domain/filename4.jpg |

Comment: Filenames are never URLs . URLs should be present for download button.

Comment: @nice_dev I do not understand. Can you give me some example?

Comment: File names should be directly displayed as names, as they are on the disk. If the user wants to download it, you can make an anchor tag link as a download option. What's the point of having file names as http URLs?

Comment: @nice_dev `What's the point of having file names as http URLs?` for online stores

Comment: @nice_dev I need to send csv file with 65,000 records with full path for images.

Comment: So, where is the code that displays the table?

Comment: @nice_dev no display table, only download button `value="Download File"`

Comment: @nice_dev export csv from mysql database not table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you're looking for?

```
$sql = "SELECT caption, concat('http://example.com/', filename) as filename
FROM table";
```

Comment: seriously, it was so easy :) I didn't know it could be that way and I spent 2 days on it